Как задать значение по умолчанию
Есть такой код. Мне нужно что бы при создании Attribute в name в обязательном порядке было значение по умолчанию. Хотя бы пустое. Варианты с Optional вроде как мне не подходят потому что тогда и _name должен быть _name: T|None, а мне так не надо. А код вроде name: T=T() не работает, потому что как я понял T это именно TypeVar, а не условный int или str в которые он потом почему-то не конвертируется. Что делать?
class Attribute[T]:
   _name: T
   ...
   
   
   def __init__(self, name: T= ?):
      self._name = name
      ...


Почему именно Optional не подходит? Да, тогда _name должно быть типа T | None, но это и есть "хотя бы пустое".

@insolor , просто я хочу что бы 1) _name был однозначным 2) мне нужно будет его возвращать, а если он может принимать форму None то потом постоянно нужно будет делать проверку на тип (None это или условный str). Ну короче я много об этом думал и пришел к выводу что это будет не очень удобно. Если name будет в случае с str иметь значение "", а в случае с тем же int значение 0, это решит мою проблему, но я не знаю как это сделать.

Задать T = TypeVar("T", int, str) (перечислить все допустимые типы), а в классе def __init__(self, name: T = ""):

@ArtemiiSelyankin, как вариант можно сделать, чтобы _name могло быть неинициализированным (но тогда хранить какой-то флаг, или через hasattr проверять, инициализировано _name или нет).

Либо при инициализации объекта передавать функцию, которая будет создавать значение по умолчанию, типа def __init__(self, default_factory: Callable([], T)): self._name = default_factory()

В целом нормальный вариант - хранить _name: T | None, и например при запросе имени кидать исключение, если оно пустое, или возвращать однозначный тип T.

@insolor , ну пожалуй остановлюсь на варианте с исключением.
